WireGuard tunnel on Mikrotik working "one way"
I have two remote locations.
Location 1: MKT-KRK - Mikrotik with public IP (11.12.13.14)
Location 2: MKT-BRZ - Mikrotik - no public IP
R1 - BRZ - public IP (15.16.17.18)
Network diagram below:

Location 1 MIkrotik acts as a WG server with public IP;
Location 2 has Mikrotik configured as peer (connects automatically to the MKT-KRK).
I want to connect both locations with a tunnel so devices from both LAN's can ping each other and exchange traffic.
Mikrotiks inside tunnel can ping each other.
MKT-BRZ can ping also all IP's inside LAN-KRK.
But MKR-KRK can ping only MKT-BRZ but cannot any IP inside LAN-BRZ

I have simple routes:
All traffic from MKT-KRK going to 192.168.2.0 (LAN - BRZ) will be routed via WG gateway and vice versa on the other side.
I also have some Firewall rules that allow traffic on both sides but I'm not sure of these if there's something blocking it...
Below are my firewall & routes settings for both Mikrotik's:
MKT-KRK:
Firewall:
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=input comment="::: allow WireGuard " dst-port=5555 log-prefix=wg_ protocol=udp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment="Block WWW on WAN" dst-port=80 in-interface=WAN log=yes protocol=tcp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment="Block DNS requests on WAN" dst-port=53 in-interface=WAN protocol=udp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment=Api dst-port=8728 in-interface=WAN log=yes protocol=tcp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment=Api-SSL dst-port=8729 in-interface=WAN log=yes protocol=tcp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment="Winbox port" dst-port=8291 in-interface=WAN log=yes protocol=tcp
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input comment="Block ping on WAN but allow from MKT" connection-mark=!ping_from_mkt in-interface=WAN log=yes protocol=icmp
/ip firewall filter add action=log chain=input comment="Log all connections to MKT on WAN except UDP" connection-mark=!ping_from_mkt in-interface=WAN log-prefix=to_mkt_ protocol=!udp
/ip firewall filter add action=log chain=input comment="Log all incoming via WireGuard" in-interface=mkt-krk-wg log-prefix=to_mkt_
/ip firewall mangle add action=mark-connection chain=output comment="Ping from MKT to WAN" new-connection-mark=ping_from_mkt out-interface=WAN passthrough=yes protocol=icmp
/ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="Masquerade" out-interface=pppoe-out1
/ip firewall nat add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="redir1" dst-port=5000 log=yes log-prefix=nvr-redir_ protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.1.5 to-ports=34567

Routes:
#     DST-ADDRESS     GATEWAY     DISTANCE
  DAv 0.0.0.0/0       pppoe-out1         1
  DAc 11.12.13.255/32  pppoe-out1         0
  DAc 192.168.0.0/24  mkt-krk-wg         0
  DAc 192.168.1.0/24  LAN                0
0  As 192.168.2.0/24  mkt-krk-wg         1

MKT-BRZ:
Firewall:
/ip firewall address-list add address=192.168.1.0/24 list=LAN-KRK
/ip firewall address-list add address=192.168.2.0/24 list=LAN-BRZ
/ip firewall connection tracking set udp-timeout=30s
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=input comment="::: allow WireGuard" dst-port=5555 protocol=udp src-address=11.12.13.14
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
/ip firewall filter add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="defconf: fasttrack" connection-state=established,related hw-offload=yes
/ip firewall filter add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept established,related, untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
/ip firewall nat add action=accept chain=srcnat log=yes src-address=192.168.1.0/24
/ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="Masquerade" ipsec-policy=out,none out-interface-list=WAN

Routes:
Flags: D - DYNAMIC; A - ACTIVE; c - CONNECT, s - STATIC, d - DHCP
Columns: DST-ADDRESS, GATEWAY, DISTANCE
#     DST-ADDRESS       GATEWAY        DISTANCE
  DAd 0.0.0.0/0         192.168.254.1         1
  DAc 192.168.0.0/24    mkt-brz-wg            0
0  As 192.168.1.0/24    mkt-brz-wg            1
  DAc 192.168.2.0/24    LAN-bridge            0
  DAc 192.168.254.0/24  eth1-WAN              0


I suspect the problem is that your systems on LAN-BRZ point their default route to R1-BRZ and this causes all return traffic from LAN-KRK to go there and eventually be dropped. You either need to re-think your topology or put static routes on all LAN-BRZ nodes which point to LAN-KRK through MKT-BRZ as a gateway.

Currently R1-BRZ has a static route added that sends all traffic intended for LAN-KRK to 192.168.2.2

My next step would be to look at the firewall, but what you pasted is completely incomprehensible, so you are on your own. Or just do /ip/firewall/export terse show-sensitive and improve your question... MKT-KRK routes can also be formatted better.

I edited the question and now all the rules & routes should be much more readable.

The ping looks like you don't have a route to the BRZ LAN... Have you tried to traceroute? Or ping 192.168.2.2?

I thought that having 192.168.2.0/24 via mkt-krk-wg route is sufficient... For the moment I'm using unsecure pptp and it works - I would have to try this one more time with WireGuard...
